# C Makefile with header in other directories

Tags: c, gcc

Here's the sample structure.

```
                main.c
                  | 
    --------------  
    |                                 
dir0-"sum.h","sum.c"
```

`sum` and `sub` are just two simple functions, located in `dir0`. They're called in `main.c`.

I'm trying to compile using gcc `gcc -Idir0 main.c sum.c -o main`. 
But it throws an error that it cannot find `sum.c`.

Besides, how to use `-I` flag with two sub-directory.

Comment: Don't spam tags. `g++` is the C++ compiler frontend. And what **specifically** about the gcc docomentation did you not understand?

Comment: `gcc ../sum.c <...>` ...? Also, have you consulted the documentation at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should be:

```
 gcc -Idir0 main.c dir0/sum.c -o main
```

Notice that sum.c is in a sub-directory and you have to tell the compiler that.